# How do I declare a generic async Task?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following method:

```
public async Task<List<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
```

Which is fine, returns a list of Products.

However I'd like to make this generic - something like...

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
```

But I'm struggling with syntax and I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost there:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync<T>()
```

Comment: Please give a sample of the method implementation as well since, the return type would not be simple. Using the signature you have mentioned one would need to also write: return Task.FromResult<T>(result);

Answer (score 4):

Creating generic method that returns a task is not different from creating a generic method returning anything else:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetStuffAsync<T>() {
    ...
}
```

You need to provide a generic type parameter `T` to make the syntax work. Generally, though you would probably want something else to generate that list inside the method, for example

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetStuffAsync<T>(Func<T> gen) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The method actually just calls a REST service - a GET on the resource that has the same name as the class, so pretty simple. But yes I can see that at some point I may need you second option. So thanks for that.